# Force only part of a page into IE7 compatibility mode

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-7, compatibility

I know you can force a whole page in IE8 or IE9 to render in IE7 mode by adding the meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
```

But how can I make it so only part of the page gets rendered in this compatibility mode? I don't want to use iframes.

Comment: More context (what/why) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. But if you have access to the page, why can't you make it entirely compatible with all versions of IE?